# Summarize a specific column and have that one column printed out instead of all?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby, data-science, data-analysis

I'm new to python data analysis, sorry if the question is simplistic lol I am summarizing my data using the groupby method to get the total number of parts for each year, I have got the answer but when I print out the table I don't want to include all the other columns as well.

The Image shows my output (on the right) vs what I am trying to achieve on the left:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
themes_by_year = sets.groupby('year')['theme_id'].size().reset_index()
```

Hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

> If You want to display a column, you just have to add it like : df[‘name of column’].
>   In your case : theme_by_year[‘theme_id’].head()

So, you don't want to sum but to count?

```
theme_by_year = sets.groupby('year')['theme_id'].count().reset_index()
theme_by_year.head()
```

Comment: But the desired output is on left. so we have to count the theme_id for each year, not the sum of theme_id.